# "Publish to Folder" in Visual Studio Mac, my static files are missing when running but are in the published files

Tags: c#, .net-core, publish, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac

When I run my .net core (7) project from inside Visual Studio in either Windows or MacOS, everything is fine.  I see my website served as expected.  When I "publish to folder", and run that generated console app in MacOS, none of my static files are found by the web page.  This includes bootstrap, jquery, and telerik libraries, as well as the favicon. The files exist in the published wwwroot folder What is the correct publish settings to get this to work properly?  I have app.UseStaticFiles() and that doesn't seem to matter on MacOS.
I've tried a couple of things including putting all the files in the root folder, and i've also played with the publish settings of the individual files.  Nothing has helped.

[image]

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Note:  I've also tried removing `app.UseAuthorization()`

Comment: Can you share your project structure? Have you placed them into `wwwroot` folder?

Comment: I've got more details for you.  I just ran it on my work computer and it installed and is working.  I will not be able to give you any more information until this evening but i'm going to copy the deployment settings from this computer and see if i can find some differences.  My js files are in wwwroot inside a js folder, and same with css files, except for bootstrap and jquery which are nested under a lib folder inside wwwroot.

Comment: I'm going to delete this question after enough time i've sure you have seen this comment, @GuruStron.  I changed some publish settings to "single file" (which failed) and when i put them back it was suddenly working.  Possible bug in 2022 i suppose.

Comment: Sometimes `git clean -fdx` helps to solve some local issues (be sure that everything needed is committed). Also try publishing via `dotnet` CLI command. VS sometimes can have quirks.

Comment: There's definitely something strange going on.  I am not having the problem on windows but i'm still having it on the mac.  It's not serving any of the static files in the wwwroot folder at all.  Not even the favicon.  The exact same project looks correct in windows but it's absolutely wrong in macos.  I have the app.usestaticfiles set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because on Osx wwwroot location is pointing to a wrong place instead of the root folder running the application.

Try this on the Configure method to test on MAC:

```
if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.OSX))
   app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
       {FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "wwwroot")),RequestPath = ""});
```

If it works just add an else:

```
else
       app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: ok.  I suspected a bug.  I'll let you know if this works shortly.  I'm about to test it.

Comment: Yes!  You're the best.  Thanks for that.  I can't award the bounty for 20 hours but you're getting it.

Comment: is the else really necessary though?  Seems like your modification would work cross-platform.

Comment: ok you've got the rep.  I opened up a support ticket with microsoft.  Hopefully they can reproduce.

Comment: this apparently breaks running the code in the IDE now.  The wwwroot folder is two levels higher than the debug dll.  For some reason you can't catch the pathnotfound error.  I'm getting sick of all these weird issues in vsmac.  I put a debugmode check to skip your code and run the normal usestaticfiles() and it was throwing the error anyway.  It does however run when publish so that's all that matters.  I can do the development on my pc.

Comment: If you provide details we can ask for a potential further issue between code and osx

Comment: I had to make some code changes to it to get it to work properly when "publish to single file" is used.  The reflection code wasn't working and was returning null.  Revised code in an answer so you can see what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based off of jmvcollaborator's answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76376825/9008140.
I was getting compile problems whenever I changed publish settings in any manner.  When I chose "Publish to single file" (which still isn't a single file, confusingly), the reflection code to get the path would fail.  Here is revised code that seems to work when "publish to single file" is used.  I believe it's building a docker container internally, based on the errors I was getting.

```
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
    {
        var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); // Or whatever method you are using
        string path = process.MainModule.FileName.Replace("TwinklyWeb", "wwwroot");
        Console.WriteLine("OSX detected.  Looking for static files here: " + path);
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path),
            RequestPath = ""
        }); ;
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do two things:

1. Right click on the file and select Quick Properties -> Copy to Output Directory (if your files are actually present in the output directory, you don't need to do this)
2. I use this function to get the correct relative path when referencing files:

```
string getFullPath(string relativePath)
{
    string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    return System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDirectory, relativePath);
}
```